# Explanation of a few lines of code

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist, foreach

I'm having a little difficulty understand these lines of code.

```
ArrayList<Member> results = null;
 try {
   results = MemberSQL.member();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


Object[] header = { "name","lastname", "ID", "Phone", "Race", "Member",
    "Divorced", "Married", "Single", "Location" };

  Object[][] data = new Object[results.size()][9]; 

  int i = 0;
  for (Member member : results) {
   data[i] = member.toObjectArray();
   i++;
  }
```

I don't understand what the ArrayList is doing - or what setting it equal to MemberSQL.member() does.

I also don't understand the Object[][] data = new Object[results.size()[9] does .. and also, why does it still work even though I remove the number 9?

the for each loop, I have no idea how to explain it.  I've said: for each object of Member, it adds data to toObjectArray located in  Member. Is this true? I have no idea :/

If anyone would help me to explain every single line of code,preferably in depth, I'd be forever thankful.
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did. It did not explain it well enough for me to understand.

Comment: `explain every single line of code, preferably in depth` seems like a silly request.

Comment: `results` holds the results of (I guess) SQL query, represented as a bunch of instances of `Member` class. It's used to allocate and fill an array containing alternative representation of `Member`: each`Member` is represented as `Object[]`. The `9` is indeed redundant.

Comment: I was just looking for a little help to make me understand it better. Can't see anything wrong with that?

I find it weird that people give me "thumbs" down. I am genuinely asking for help on something that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Member> results = null;
```

initializes an array of type Member

```
 try {
   results = MemberSQL.member();
```

MemberSQL.member is a function that returns an ArrayList of type Member

```
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


Object[] header = { "name","lastname", "ID", "Phone", "Race", "Member",
    "Divorced", "Married", "Single", "Location" };
```

creates an array of Objects with the string values shown in between the { }

```
  Object[][] data = new Object[results.size()][9];
```

creates a two dimensional array of Objects.

```
  int i = 0;
  for (Member member : results) {
```

loop through each item in the results array.

```
   data[i] = member.toObjectArray();
```

member.toObjectArray() is a function that returns an object array. data[i] is set to this value.

```
   i++;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! :) 

Do you know why I can't see any difference when I don't write anything where the number 9 is? I can leave it empty just fine without any errors - not even when I run my program.

Comment: it is a two dimensional array and that is simply a number that explains the array size. It goes [#rows][#columns]

Comment: Ahh lovely! Thanks so much for the help. You just taught me a few things :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things we don't know from this code.  Specifically, we don't know what a `Member` is, and we don't know what `MemberSQL` is.  But that's OK, we don't really need to in order to explain what's happening here.

> I don't understand what the ArrayList is doing - or what setting it equal to MemberSQL.member() does.

OK, first of all, the `ArrayList` is doing what `ArrayList`s always do -- holding a bunch of data of the same kind in a convenient container, so we can work with it as a group.  We don't know what `MemberSQL.member()` does, but we can surmise that it builds a bunch of `Member` objects and puts them into an `ArrayList`.  When we set `results = MemberSQL.member()`, it means that we want to run the MemberSQL.member() method, and hold onto its returned value as our `results` variable.

> I also don't understand the Object[][] data = new Object[results.size()[9] does .. and also, why does it still work even though I remove the number 9?

This line creates a new, two-dimensional array of `Object`s.  You can think of this as a grid.  The grid has the same number of rows as the `results` list has elements, and 9 columns.  In Java, it's legal to not specify the size of the last dimension of an array, and worry about it later.  That's why it still works if you leave the 9 out.

> the for each loop, I have no idea how to explain it. I've said: for each object of Member, it adds data to toObjectArray located in Member. Is this true?

Actually, you have this backwards.  It's actually looking at the `member` and running its `toObjectArray()` method.  It's saving the result in the `data` array.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me understand it a whole lot better than before! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: It requires a reputaiton of 15 in order to do that. Seems like I need my rep to go up a bit :P

Comment: @AdemÖkmen at least you can accept either of the answers